# How to insert new object without deleting previous one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, rocket.chat

I'm setting up my new RocketChat Server.

The problem is that actually, Rocket Chat doesn't support CAS Account if they are not created by CAS.

We have old accounts.

I can add the CAS feature by doing this :

Enter in the MongoDB Database with MongoDB Compass software on Windows, and add cas object in services object with my keyboard...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/weLuk.png

So as you can see I can add the CAS feature by doing this.

I want to do that with code so I did this :

1 - Enter in rocketchat_mongo docker

2 - Connect with admin login and use rocketchat database

3 - Execute this code

```
db.users.update({"name":"Fabien Rousseau"},{ $set: {"services" : { "cas" : { "external_id" : "fabien.rousseau", "version" : 2 }}}})
```

The command is OK because CAS object is added in services, BUT, it delete the other object like password and resume...

I just want to add CAS object without deleting other objects...

My expected result is in the first image : account with CAS.

Actually after the command I have this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkJoe.png

Please help me to tune my command to avoid deleting other objects in my services object.

Comment: And i don't know why but i need 10 of reputation to put images... so sorry for the links guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole `services` (includes all other fields) to `$set`, and, as a result, you are resetting all the fields nested inside `services`. Try passing only data you want to update/add to your document using [dot notation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)
[$set documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) says

> To specify an field in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

```
db.users.update({"name":"Fabien Rousseau"},{ $set: { "services.cas" : { "external_id" : "fabien.rousseau", "version" : 2 }}})
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much it's working like I want. Now I can update all my database ! :)