# Having trouble with adding a new field to an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I try to add a field to an object, instead of adding the field to the object it deletes all of the previous fields and adds the new field.

```
data.collection.updateOne({},{$set: {"object": {"hi":0}}},true)
```

What I want:

```
object: {
      hello: 0,
      hi: 0,
}
```

What I get:

```
object: {
      hi: 0,
}
```

I tried everything I could but I did not get it to work as I wanted it to.

Comment: Check this link it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596504/how-to-insert-new-object-without-deleting-previous-one

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
 db.we.updateOne( { },{$set:{"object.hi":0 } } , true)
 WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```